# Why do we write "G-d" instead of "God"

Tags: words

Some people tend to write "G-d" instead of "God". I thought that it was for respect or maybe they don't want to erase or profane the word "God", and that seems ok.

But if I'm right, then why do we all write "Hashem"? I know it's not actually a name of God (it means "His name") but it's definitively more Kadosh than the word "God".

Comment: Some words are more direct in their addressing of him. Hashem if you Google it is used to refer to him without speaking his name. The reason you don't write his name is so that nobody can destroy it.

Comment: @GettingNifty Then why was "is" written? Why not I-? Or is it OK to us his name in other languages besides Hebrew.